# How can i put variable into load function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How can i put variable into "load" function ?
- i need to recover source filename and put in location

```
function updateClock() {
    var loc = $(location).attr('pathname');
    // $("#clock").load('index.php #clock');  <- this one is working but I need variable 
    $("#clock").load('$loc #clock'); < -problem with $loc variable(how to implement)
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put your variable in string value like

```
$("#clock").load('$loc #clock');
```

interpreter thinks that as a string.. so put it outside and make it like...

```
$("#clock").load(loc + ' ' + '#clock');
```

that should work.

Comment: Already tried this way but it doesn't work but the idea is good.
The solution is : 
$("#clock").load(loc + ' ' + '#clock');

Thanks !

Comment: So check for loc value with console.log(loc); in proper place. Maybe it is undefined by your code.

Answer (score 0):

With help from user "tanaydin", the solution is :

```
$("#clock").load(loc + ' ' + '#clock');
```